# 'group_concat' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-concat

I been looking into group_concat, but it isn't working on SQL 2012, From what i have figured is that i have to have a functions to do so. But here is my question, i'm sending a SQLQuery by some c# code and want to return a datatabel.

'001' '123' '456' (and keep on going until we cannot find anymore phone number that is attached to the Cosnr.

From what i get now is.
'001' 123'
'001' 345'

Is there anyway, to send a single SQLQuery form C# to get back a datatabel looking like 
'001' '123' '456'

Hope anyone can help me. :)

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` is a MySQL function, but not a SQL Server function. You can simulate this with the XML functionality.

Comment: Correct.  `group_concat()` is a MySQL function.  It is a bit painful to do in SQL Server, but there are many examples if you search on aggregation string concatenation.

Comment: How does your tables look like? What's the content of the tables and what's your query statement? What's the connection to group_concat?

Comment: The query is:
SELECT name, lastnavn, companyname, adresse, postnr, email, phone FROM customer
INNER JOIN customerEmail ON 
 [dbo].[customer].customernr = [dbo].[customerEmail].customernr
INNER JOIN [dbo].[kundetlf] ON 
 [dbo].[customer].customernr = [dbo].[customerphone].customernr
 ORDER BY name ASC;

I want to the "GROUP_CONCAT()" on the phone (Or atleast have something that has the same effect.